# Is it possible to return a setter in function call in javascript?

Tags: javascript, setter

```
class Person{
  set name(value){
    this._name = value;
  }
  get name(){
    return this._name;
  }

  modify(){
    return this.name;
  }

}


const adam = new Person();
adam.name = 'Adam'; //assign new value to setter :)
adam.modify() = 'Adam'; //assign new value to getter :(
```

I wonder if it is possible to return a setter in the called function like in the example above. The example does not work because the `adam.modify` called function returns `getter` (it calls `this.name` `getter` method) so the new value `'Adam'` is in fact assigned to the returned primitive value `undefined` as I guess and not to the the `adam._name` property.

What I want to do is to make the example from above work, that is `adam.modify() = 'Adam';` should assing new value to `adam._name`. Is it possible in any way?

I'm writing my own private framework and I wish it would look like this, eg. `$cell('C22') = 100;`
The only way I have figured it out so far is to make it that way `$cell('C22').value = 1000;` but I wish the function could return the setter itself.

Comment: You can redefine the property details with `Object.defineProperty()`, or use `Object.getPropertyDescriptor()` to get the current descriptor. It's completely unclear what you want to do; returning a value, getter or no getter, is not going to allow you to use a simple assignment to update it.

Comment: AFAIK, the desired syntax is invalid JavaScript. `Uncaught ReferenceError: cannot assign to function call`